# Makefile - Pattern Rule as a dependency

Tags: makefile

I've ha makefile with following entries. Will the first rule depend on the secon rule ? So that it builds all the .o files from second files ?

```
all:$(PROG)
$(PROG): *.o 
    $(LD) -o $(PROG) -c $<  $(LFLAGS)

%.o : %.c 
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

To be specific if i invoke 'make all' will it invoke the second rule if no *.o files were found ?
All other Variables have usual meaning .

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not work.  When you run your makefile for the first time, are there any `.o` files?  No.  So the expression `*.o` will expand to nothing.

Of course, your recipe for `$(PROG)` doesn't actually use any of the object files anyway, as written.

You can do something like this (although personally I prefer to simply list the files out by hand; it's not very common to create all new files so it's not much effort, and it's safer than just trying to grab every file in the directory):

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

$(PROG): $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: In this case how do I give a rule saying every *.o file depends on corresponding .c file ?When I change a single c file I only want to recompile the .c file that was changed and not the whole set of c files

Comment: Sure.  My example was not intended to be a complete makefile.  It only provided the part of the makefile that defines prerequisites for `$(PROG)`, since that was the part related to your question.  However, make has built-in rules that know how to build a `.o` file from a `.c` file.  You don't have to provide a rule to do that, if you don't want to.  If you do, then you should continue to use a pattern rule such as the one in your question.